# OpenCart QuickCheckout passing variable between functions

Tags: php, opencart-3

I have a variable $foo which I want to use to store a value.
I want to reference a variable $foo in a different function.
Nothing I have tried works.
The Error Log shows:  PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:

I have tried setting it as a Global variable.  No good.
Tried Private Static.  ditto
This should be simple - load a value in a variable in one function, retrieve the value in a different function (different PHP modules, all called from the same Controller Extension

Experienced programmer ASP, C, etc. -- PHP newbie
Obviously I am missing something.  What am I missing?

OpenCart 3.0.3.6
MarketinSG QuickCheckOut current version

Comment: Show some code please. What have you tried?

Comment: In Coupon.php the information I am trying to capture is here:  (float)$order_total['value']

Comment: Both coupon.php and confirm.php are called from checkout.php

In coupon.php, the data I want is here:  
    (float)$order_total['value'] 
I create a new variable and assign it: 
   $discount_applied = (float)$order_total['value'] ;

In confirm.php I try to capture the value of that variable here:
    $order_data['commission'] =  $discount_applied;

Does not work.  There is no data in $discount_applied.

Comment: Are you passing the data $foo to the controller? Normally in a controller file the data is being passed to the view like this `return $this->load->view('some/path', $data);` and variables are being stored like this `$data['foo']`, finally being called on the .twig like this: `{{ foo }}`

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.  I will check and confirm.  Appreciate the assistance